# Google Play Services gerando erros

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá. Ao **adicionar** o **Google Play Services** as dependências, o erro da imagem é apresentado. Não faço a menor ideia do motivo, ou de como soluciona-lo.

- O erro só é apresentado no arquivo **values-21.xml**
- Após **remover** o **Google Play Services** das dependências, o erro parece ser solucionado, sendo possível efetuar a compilação normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Como está o seu `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: @ramaral

 compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é devido ao facto de estar a declarar `compileSdkVersion=19`.

O arquivo `values-21.xml` usa *resources* que só existem a partir da versão 21.

A aplicação terá, por isso, de ser compilada no mínimo com a versão 21 do Android.
No entanto, o ideal é você compilar sempre os seus projecto usando a versão mais actual do SDK.

Se ainda não o fez, faça o *download* da última versão da API Android disponível, que nesta data é a 6.0 API 23. Actualize também o *Tools* para a ultima versão.

Feito isso, altere o valor de `compileSdkVersion` para 23

Comment: ramaral, o problema do `values-21.xml` é porque ele está usando o `appcompat-v7:22.2.0`, e o `values-21.xml` pertence ao `appcompat` (não daria pra remover), que exige que o app seja compilado com a versão 21 do android, da pra ver isso pelo caminho do arquivo que fica no topo. De resto concordo plenamente com sua resposta :D

Comment: @Wakim. Então, se entendi bem, o que não está correcto na minha resposta seria apenas a possibilidade de de remover o arquivo, certo?.

Comment: Exato, ele não pertence ao app em sim, é interno do `appcompat-v7` na versão `22.2.0`.

Comment: @Wakim Obrigada, vou editar a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Parece algum problema com o Gradle, vá em Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files e veja se resolve.

Também verifica se sua SDK do play services está atualizada na última revision 27.

Comment: Não resolveu. Sim, está na revision 27. Fiz questão de atualiza-lo antes de adicionar o Play Services.